# Can I use ethminer with just OpenGL

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I have created a windows server EC2/GPU instance, downloaded the proper version of ethermine and tried to start mining. It says that it won't work thanks to no OpenCL or CUDa. This is confirmed by documentation which states that Elastic GPUs only support OpenGL and not OpenCL or Cuda. There are EC2 GPU Compute instances that I can confirm work, however, they are expensive. Is there a version of an ethereum mining that will work on an OpenGL only machine?